# How to use SUBTOTAL with COUNTIFS function?

Tags: excel, function

I use this function

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Combined!B:B;Sheet1!B3;Combined!K:K;{"1";"2";"3";"4";"G";"L";"Π"}))
```

and I need to sum only visible cells from the sheet "Combined".

I also tried to use SUBTOTAL:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Combined!B:B=Sheet1!B3)*(Combined!K:K={"1";"2";"3";"4";"G";"L";"Π"}‌​);SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(Combined!B:B;ROW(Combined!B:B)-MIN(ROW(Combined!B:B));0;1;1‌​)))
```

How can I get my result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data begins in row 2 (amend as appropriate):

`=SUMPRODUCT((Combined!B2:B100=Sheet1!B3)*(Combined!K2:K100={"1","2","3","4","G","L","Π"})*SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(Combined!B2,ROW(Combined!B2:B100)-MIN(ROW(Combined!B2:B100)),)))`

Note that you should not use entire column references within SUMPRODUCT.

With some functions, e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), you can get away with referencing entire columns with no detriment to performance, though not with functions which operate over arrays, such as AGGREGATE, SUMPRODUCT, and any construction requiring CSE.

Choose a suitably low, though sufficient, upper bound for the end row being referenced (I chose 100 here) or, even better, makes your ranges dynamic, such that they automatically adjust as your data expands/contracts.

Regards